# Image fails to save in Parallel.For loop

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am using Parallel.For loop to process some images. When I try to save the image, sometimes I get an exception-

> a generic error occurred in gdi+

Some images gets saves then this exception comes randomly after saving few files.

- I tried assigning the original bitmap image object to a different Bitmap image and then saving it
- Tried using `Monitor.Enter` to synchronize between saving the files

Below is my code-

```
Parallel.For(0, 14, cnt =>
{
    using (Bitmap originalImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@imagePath))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < originalImage.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < originalImage.Height; x++)
            {
                System.Drawing.Color oc = originalImage.GetPixel(i, x);
                int gray = (int)((oc.R * 0.3) + (oc.G * 0.59) + (oc.B * 0.11));
                System.Drawing.Color nc = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(oc.A, gray, gray, gray);
                originalImage.SetPixel(i, x, nc);
            }
        }
        try
        {
            //Bitmap grayscaleImage = originalImage;
            //grayscaleImage.Save(@processesImagesPath + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh.mm.ss") + ".jpg");  //line of exception

            //above lines did not work

            Monitor.Enter(originalImage);
            originalImage.Save(@processesImagesPath + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh.mm.ss") + ".jpg");  //line of exception
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(originalImage);
        }
    }   
});
```

Comment: `imagePath` is always the same in `Parallel.For`?

Comment: @Backs Nope. Sorry. I updated the code, check now.

Comment: I don't see usoing of `cnt` variable. It seems, you try to update one file 14 times in parallel

Comment: Yeah it's a simulation, so `cnt` is unused for now

Comment: Having 14 threads doing IO in parallel will result in a fight over access to the disk. You might be able to speed things up by having multiple threads generating the grayscaled images in memory and have a single thread reading and writing writing them.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Thanks. Didn't think about that. So how do I do that?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd So you mean I can just save them within a collection and at the end write them one by one?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Just test it and see if/how it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh.mm.ss")` - two images can be saved in one second, you will get an error. Create more unique filename.
For example:

`var filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh.mm.ss") + cnt`